# Is there a way to set Highchart options dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, highcharts

Is it possible to toggle chart dataLabels (enabled/disabled) on click (without redrawing the chart) much like the following:

```
('.inner-container').click(function() {
    chart.setTitle({text: "New Title"});
});
```

I have tried the method below but it does not work.

```
('.inner-container').click(function() {
    chart.setOptions({dataLabels: {enabled: true}});
});
```

I can't seem to find any details on how to set chart options dynamically in the documentation. If anyone could point me in the right direction then that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can set `chart.options` directly i think

Comment: In the official doc at "http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts", there is a section "Methods and properties" described as "For dynamically modifying the chart. View as JSON, XML.". You didn't find your happiness there ?

Comment: To disable your text property of Title, you just set the **text** to **null** as shown here:http://jsfiddle.net/HFurV/

Comment: @Ricola3D Thanks, yea It's not clear enough for me to figure out how to change the options dynamically. Perhaps if someone doesn't mind they could spend a second to explain why 'chart.options({dataLabels: {enabled: true}});' doesn't work. From the documentation I had managed to change the title (as per my initial post) but I can't understand how to change the dataLabel options. Thanks.

Comment: Because in Highcharts there is not such method like `chart.options()` set `chart.setOptions` - all methods to overwride options are listed as @Ricola3D posted. You can update: series/axis/points. Not chart itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I managed to figure it out, by using the series.update() method.

```
chart.series[0].update({
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
    }
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: perfect - exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Additional solution, based on datalabels elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/eNMvw/37/

```
chart.series[0].hideDataLabels = false;

// Add toggler action
$('#toggler').click(function() {
    chart.series[0].hideDataLabels = !chart.series[0].hideDataLabels;
    chart.series[0].hide();
    chart.series[0].show();
});
```